# retrieving all Foreign Keys and their records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, nested, procedure

What I'm trying to achieve is the following.
When I delete a record I want to check if there are any FK relationships and it needs to be recursive. That way I can display a list of all records that are related to the one you want to delete.

So a  small example of nested links
project 1 -> phase 1 -> block 1 -> ..

So when I try to delete project 1 I need to get a list of the items you need to delete first:
phase 1
block 1
....

I wanted to do this with a stored procedure that takes an ID and a tablename (format [chema].[tablename]) and finds all these linked records.

The problem I'm having is with the recursive part.
Here's my code so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE core.usp_CanBeDeleted    
    @entityId int,
    @entityName nvarchar(250)   
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @NumberRecords int, @RowCount int
    DECLARE @childId int
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @eName nvarchar(250) , @keyName nvarchar(250) 
    DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(250)

    DECLARE @keys TABLE(
        RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1), 
        name nvarchar(250),
        entityName nvarchar(250),
        columnName nvarchar(250)
    )

    if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='partialResults' and xtype='U')
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE partialResults(
            RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1), 
            id int,
            parentId int,
            name nvarchar(250),
            FK_name nvarchar(250)
        )
    END

    DECLARE @recusiveResults TABLE(
        RowID int, 
        id int,
        parentId int,
        name nvarchar(250),
        FK_name nvarchar(250)
    )

    DECLARE @results TABLE(
        RowID int, 
        id int,
        parentId int,
        name nvarchar(250),
        FK_name nvarchar(250)
    )

    SET @RowCount = 1

        -- get all FK's of the entity
    INSERT INTO @keys
    SELECT name, '[' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '].[' +     OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)+ ']',cu.column_name
    from sys.foreign_keys k
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON k.name = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    where k.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@entityName)

    -- set variable to number of records in temp table
    SET @NumberRecords = @@ROWCOUNT

    -- loop through the FK's an get all linked entities
    WHILE(@RowCount <= @NumberRecords)
    BEGIN

        SELECT @keyName = name, @eName = entityName, @columnName = columnName
        FROM @keys
        WHERE RowId = @RowCount 

        -- get all FK information
        SET @query = 'INSERT INTO partialResults(FK_name, name, id, parentId)'
        + ' SELECT ''' + @keyName + ''','''+  @eName + ''',' + 'id,' +         cast(@entityId as varchar(25)) + ' as parentid'
        + ' FROM  ' +@eName
        + ' WHERE id in '
        + ' (SELECT ' + @columnName 
            + ' FROM ' + @entityName 
            + ' WHERE id = ' + cast(@entityId as varchar(25))
            + ' )'

        --print @query                                              
        EXEC (@query)

        SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1
    END

    -- rest number of records
    SET @RowCount = 1
    SELECT @NumberRecords = count(id) 
    FROM partialResults 

    -- save partialResults  
    INSERT INTO @results--(FK_name, name, id, parentId)
    SELECT *--FK_name, name, id, parentId
    FROM partialResults 

    DELETE FROM partialResults

    WHILE(@RowCount <= @NumberRecords)
        BEGIN
        -- select next row
        SELECT @childId = id, @eName = name
        FROM @results
        WHERE RowId = @RowCount                                 

        INSERT INTO @recusiveResults        
        EXEC core.usp_CanBeDeleted @childId, @eName

        SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT *
    FROM @recusiveResults

    if exists (select * from sysobjects where name='partialResults' and xtype='U')
    BEGIN
        -- remove temp tables
        DROP TABLE partialResults
    END
    -- return results
    SELECT * 
    FROM @results       
END
GO
```

the problem lies here:

```
INSERT INTO @recusiveResults        
EXEC core.usp_CanBeDeleted @childId, @eName
```

Apparantly you can't nest an insert exec.
however I don't really see any other way to do it.
I've tried converting it into a function but then there are other problems like the dynamic query.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the procedure into an outer and an inner procedure.

In the outer procedure create a #results temp-table and then call the inner procedure.

In the inner procedure put all the logic including the recursion, but instead of selecting out the result at the end insert the result into the already existing #results table.

That way you safe a lot of time because you dont have to move data around as much. You also don't have to nest `INSERT...EXEC` anymore.

You also don't need the `dbo.PartialResults` table anymore as you can write directly into the #results table within the dynamic statement. If you still need it, to make the recursion work replace it with a #partialResults temp table that you create in the inner procedure (DON'T check for existence, just create the new one. See http://sqlity.net/en/1109/temp-tables-scoping-eclipsing/ for an explanation of temp table scoping). That way each execution is creating its own temp table and you don't have to deal with the clean-up. This is also a little less heavy compared to using a real table.

Finally, all the table variables can go too.

At the end of the inner procedure you can then do a simple `SELECT * FROM #results;` to output all the collected results.

Comment: thanks sebastian, I'll give that a try.
the started out a lot simpler, but I kept adding things to try and fix the problems.
I figured I would need an inner and outer procedure but kinda lost my way :-)

Comment: It worked. I still needed the extra #partialResults temp table to avoid an infinite loop.

Otherwise I would add rows to Results, loop over the results and add more rows to results in each loop... that wouldn't be the best of ideas.

Anyway if anyone is interested in the final code I will post it later, because I don't have much time at the moment.